"TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on Index with these indexers [gen9ou] of type str" when running Dash app
I am getting the aformentioned error whenever I try to run my Dash app via my callback function. Over here, I am trying to create a line graph that filters data based on a given tier and top n used Pokemon in said tier. Whenever I run my code, it traces my error to about the area that I marked below. Could someone give me an answer for why am I getting a TypeError over there?
def update_graph(top_n, given_tier):
    # Filter df_final by the selected tier
    filtered_df = df_final[df_final['Tier'] == given_tier]

    sorted_df = df_final.sort_values(by=['Month', 'Usage Rate'], ascending=[False, False])
    #Get the first top_n rows in order to extract the pokemon names
    first_n_rows = sorted_df.head(top_n) <---Traced Error
    top_n_array = first_n_rows['Name'].values
    # print(sorted_df)
    # print(top_5_array)

    # Make an empty df with columns 'Name' and 'Usage Rate'
    concat_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Usage Rate', 'Month', 'Tier'])
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)
    # i = specific name
    for i in top_n_array:
        specific_name = sorted_df.loc[sorted_df['Name'] == i, ['Name', 'Usage Rate', 'Month', 'Tier']]
        concat_df = pd.concat([concat_df, specific_name], ignore_index=True)

    print(concat_df)

    fig = px.line(concat_df, x='Month', y='Usage Rate', color="Name", title=f'Top {top_n} Results')
    fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(autorange=True))
    return fig

I used my sample dataset from an excel file with the column names: Rank, Name, Usage Rate, Raw Usage, Raw %, Tier, Month. I am trying to create a line graph in plotly Dash that I can filter based on tier (gen9ou, gen9uu, gen9ru, etc) and top n mons used in said tier.

I recommend adding print statements or breakpoints if you can and finding the exact line it breaks. Then update your original post, specifying the line that causes the error

Welcome to SO. Next time, make sure to add a sample dataframe.

First of all, in your code you sort df_final instead of filtered_df. This means that the top N Pokémon might be selected from the entire dataset instead of just from the filtered tier. Also your function does not account for the different months when selecting the top N Pokémon. Finally,  you selected the top N rows directly from the sorted dataframe, which is notcorrect. You can try this approach:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Larger sample DataFrame to test
data = {
    'Rank': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'Name': ['Pikachu', 'Charizard', 'Bulbasaur', 'Squirtle', 'Jigglypuff', 'Gengar',
             'Pikachu', 'Charizard', 'Bulbasaur', 'Squirtle', 'Jigglypuff', 'Gengar',
             'Pikachu', 'Charizard', 'Bulbasaur', 'Squirtle', 'Jigglypuff', 'Gengar'],
    'Usage Rate': [20, 15, 10, 5, 25, 30, 18, 12, 8, 4, 22, 28, 19, 14, 9, 6, 23, 29],
    'Raw Usage': [2000, 1500, 1000, 500, 2500, 3000, 1800, 1200, 800, 400, 2200, 2800, 1900, 1400, 900, 600, 2300, 2900],
    'Raw %': [2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 2.5, 3.0, 1.8, 1.2, 0.8, 0.4, 2.2, 2.8, 1.9, 1.4, 0.9, 0.6, 2.3, 2.9],
    'Tier': ['gen9ou', 'gen9ou', 'gen9ou', 'gen9uu', 'gen9uu', 'gen9ou',
             'gen9ou', 'gen9ou', 'gen9ou', 'gen9uu', 'gen9uu', 'gen9ou',
             'gen9ou', 'gen9ou', 'gen9ou', 'gen9uu', 'gen9uu', 'gen9ou'],
    'Month': ['January', 'January', 'January', 'January', 'January', 'January',
              'February', 'February', 'February', 'February', 'February', 'February',
              'March', 'March', 'March', 'March', 'March', 'March']
}
df_final = pd.DataFrame(data)

def update_graph(top_n, given_tier):
    filtered_df = df_final[df_final['Tier'] == given_tier]

    if filtered_df.empty:
        print(f"No data available for tier: {given_tier}")
        return px.line(title=f'Top {top_n} Results')

    sorted_df = filtered_df.sort_values(by=['Month', 'Usage Rate'], ascending=[False, False])

    print("Filtered and sorted DataFrame:")
    print(sorted_df)

    top_n_names = sorted_df.groupby('Month').apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(top_n, 'Usage Rate')).reset_index(drop=True)
    top_n_array = top_n_names['Name'].unique()

    print(f"Top {top_n} names: {top_n_array}")

    concat_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Usage Rate', 'Month', 'Tier'])
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)

    for i in top_n_array:
        specific_name = filtered_df.loc[filtered_df['Name'] == i, ['Name', 'Usage Rate', 'Month', 'Tier']]
        concat_df = pd.concat([concat_df, specific_name], ignore_index=True)

    print("Concatenated DataFrame for plotting:")
    print(concat_df)

    if concat_df.empty:
        print(f"No data available for the top {top_n} Pokémon in tier: {given_tier}")
        return px.line(title=f'Top {top_n} Results')

    fig = px.line(concat_df, x='Month', y='Usage Rate', color="Name", title=f'Top {top_n} Results')
    fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(autorange=True))
    return fig

fig = update_graph(3, 'gen9ou')
fig.show()

which gives you

